# Running javascript function from ajax success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently working with google maps and I want to save some locations in a database and retrieve them through an ajax call, after which I make JavaScript objects from the locations.

As for the code I am not really sure why this is not working, can someone clear this up for me?

***Chrome Console:***
Uncaught TypeError: this.processData is not a function

```js
var Locations = {
    count: 0,
    location: [],
    processData: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    getData: function () {
        'use strict';
        
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '../../php/functions/getLocations.function.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                this.processData(data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

About the comment Kevin B posted, the done part should run when the async call is complete right?
***Last edit:***

```
function getLocation() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '../../php/functions/getLocations.function.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

getLocation().done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
});
```

Comment: I edited this post with a new problem..

Comment: and it's still a dupe, but of another question: you cannot return from an asynchronous function. that is impossible.

Comment: I rolled the question back because your edit invalidated existing answers. If you have a new question you should ask it as a new question. however, the one you were going to ask is a very popular dupe; you should search first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: So I need to wait every 90 minutes when another problem pops up? 
Owyeh, I can return from an asynchronous function
`function getLocation() {
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '../../php/functions/getLocations.function.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    return data;
                }
            });
        }
        return getLocation();`

Comment: *" Owyeh, I can return from an asynchronous function"* well, you can try, but it won't work. the 90 minute delay gets smaller if you ask good questions and/or participate positively within the community (answering questions and receiving upvotes for example)

Comment: The question you posted had a really long and precise answer that helped me under the headtext jQuery: Use deferred objects. I follow this script but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123389/discussion-between-smooth-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `this` refers to the scope it was initialized in.
So in your case it is the scope of the `success`-function. It doesn't refer to the object itself.

For this to work you have to cache the reference to the object to use it inside the `success`-function or reference the object itself.

**Object reference:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: '/echo/json/',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    Locations.processData(data);
  }
});
```

**Cached `this`**

```
getData: function() {
    'use strict';
    let _this = this;
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: '/echo/json/',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        _this.processData(data);
      }
    });
  }
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLLoofy0/)**

Comment: Answer is almost there....provide an example.

Comment: Adam is right, but I get the idea. I'll try to adapt it

Comment: @Smooth added 2 specific examples. I personally would go with the second one.

Comment: I did something simular in the time you were editing the question. And I posted the results in my post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`this` is pointing to ajax settings object. Either use a $.proxy or use `this` after storing it in a variable so that you are targeting the right `context`

```
getData: function () {
        'use strict';
        var thisLocation = this;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '../../php/functions/getLocations.function.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
               thisLocation.processData(data);
```

Comment: @KevinB - the answerer hadn't provided a code sample but just alluded to the fact that `this` was wrong when I made my comment

Comment: Why useless? It's correct.

Comment: the answer already exists on the dupe target. duplicate answer -> not useful.

Comment: @Sushanth-- You shouldn't have posted it in the first place. You have enough rep to vote to close as a duplicate. Don't race to post answers to easy questions that have dozens of duplicates already.

Comment: @meagar Will keep that in mind. :)